# How to build my project with Clion Remote?

Tags: c++, cmake, remote-debugging, clion

I successfully set up a remote project in CLion. It recognizes the compiler and everything on the remote host and also synchronizes changes.
Now to my problem:
When I try to build and run the project it gives me an error that it can't find a certain lib:

```
fatal error: Eigen/SparseCore: No such file or directory
 #include <Eigen/SparseCore>
```

But when I log into the server via ssh I can go to the synced directory, run make and it compiles with no errors. I can then run the compiled app no problem.

Here's the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(projectName)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(/usr/local/PRIV)
include_directories(/usr/local/PRIV/Includes)
include_directories(/usr/local/PRIV/Includes/SubDir)
include_directories(/usr/local/PRIV/Includes/SubDir/eigen3)
include_directories(/usr/local/PRIV/Includes/SubDir/eigen3/Eigen/)
include_directories(/usr/local/PRIV/Includes/SubDir/qhull)

add_executable(
        Example/MyTopTen/Makefile
        Example/MyTopTen/MyTopTen.cc
        Example/MyTopTen/MyTopTen.h
        Example/MyTopTen/Readme.txt
        Example/Makefile
        Example/Example.cc
        )
```

I'm very new to cmake projects and Stackoverflow so if I can improve this question just let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow Eigen guide how to use it with CMake https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCMakeGuide.html

In this case your CMakeLists.txt should looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(projectName)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(myTargetName
        Example/MyTopTen/MyTopTen.cc
        Example/MyTopTen/MyTopTen.h
        Example/Example.cc
        )
target_link_libraries (myTargetName Eigen3::Eigen)
```

After that Reload CMake project in CLion via `Tools | CMake | Reset Cache and Reload Project`.